# IBM API Connect Cloud Oauth API

Tags: api, oauth, invoke, apiconnect

We want to implement Oauth autentication in IBM API Connect.

Default Oauth API has POST Token as consumes Types application/x-www-form-urlencoded and form as paremeters aswel but we need to execute the call inside an IBM Default Invoke event which is not supported.

We tried to modify POST to a GET and execute a call like

https://api.eu.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/xxxxx/api-connect-oauth/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=xxxx

But is not supported in Cloud. How can execute a token request inside a invoke execution.

[Invoke Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/279NY.png)

Answer (score 0):

In a GatewayScript action before the invoke action, try the following:

```
context.message.header.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
context.message.body.write('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=client&client_secret=secret')
```

Else you can also use the urlopen module in GatewayScript.